# Find all matrices commutating with a given matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Find all matrices commutating with $F = \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}   0&{}&{}&{}&{}&{ - {c_0}}\\   1&0&{}&{}&{}&{ - {c_1}}\\   {}&1&0&{}&{}& \vdots \\   {}&{}&1& \ddots &{}&{ - {c_{n - 3}}}\\   {}&{}&{}& \ddots &0&{ - {c_{n - 2}}}\\   {}&{}&{}&{}&1&{ - {c_{n - 1}}}   \end{array}} \right)$

How can we do then?

Comment: The following may help find established results: note that this is the Frobenius [companion matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix) of the polynomial $t^n + c_{n-1}t^{n-1} + \cdots + c_1 t + c_0$.

Answer (score 1):

This type of matrix is, as mentioned, a companion matrix...or from a different point of view as the matrix representation of a Krylov subspace (cyclic subspace with respect to some operator generated by a specific vector). It has the property that it's minimal polynomial and characteristic polynomial is the same...this being the case, you can always write the commutator of $F$ as a polynomial in $F$. See the properties section: of the Wikipedia entry on commuting matrices: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commuting_matrices